# How I can check redirect in method > Django

Tags: django

I have two methods in my view and I try check redirect in first method, but don't know how do it. Two methods > `order_create` and `order_success`. In template `order_success` have values about user info and order info, also cart clear works. I want check my redirect.

**views.py**

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order, product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear_session()

        return redirect('order:order_success')
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html', {'cart':cart, 'form':form})
```

```
def order_success(request):
    if order_create_method_redirect:
        order = Order.objects.order_by('id').last()
        return render(request, 'orders/order_success.html', {'order':order})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Empty page')
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'order'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^order$', views.order_create, name='order_create'),
    url(r'^order/success$', views.order_success, name='order_success'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem for you is that you're not using `reverse` to get the url to pass to `redirect`. However, you have a few other issues that you should correct.

One is that you should include invalid form in the context being passed to render on POST. That way the errors can be displayed to the user.

The second is that your design won't support multiple orders being placed at the same time. If X orders occur at time A, then those users are all having `order_success` lookup the latest order at the same time, they will all see the absolute last order. Instead you should include the order id in the url and redirect to that specific url on success.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    # Default to a basic form for the GET path. POST will override it.
    form = OrderCreateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order, product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear_session()
            # Only redirect on absolute success
            return redirect(
                reverse('order:order_success', kwargs={'order_id': order.id})
            )
    # Return the invalid form on POST
    return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html', {'cart':cart, 'form':form})

def order_success(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    return render(request, 'orders/order_success.html', {'order':order})
```

You'll also need to change your urls.py entry for `order_success` to include the order_id kwarg.

Comment: Thank you for your support, but if I use with id, I can view other people's orders guessing through brute force

Comment: Agreed. The id shouldn't be an auto-incrementing int but rather a guid. If that's not enough, then you can pass the order id via the session.